# How to automate the creation of a directory structure with node given an json file representing the dir structure?

Tags: node.js, automation, filesystems

Given a JSON file representing the pages I want to create a file structure for:

```
[{"id": 1, "name":"page1"}, 
 {"id": 2, "name":"page2"}, 
 {"id": 3, "name":"page3"}, ...]
```

I'd like to create a script to run with node that's going to create the directories and files for me and end up with a structure like this:

```
- Folder "pages"
   - Folder "page1"
      - Folder "page"
         - index file
      - index file
   - Folder "page2"
      - Folder "page"
         - index file
      - index file
```

etc...

Any help appreciated thanks!

UPDATE:

```
structure.js:
const structure = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'home'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'about'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'work'
  }
];
module.exports = structure;

build.js:
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const structure = require('./structure');

try {
  if (!fse.existsSync('pages')) {
    fse.mkdir('pages', () => {
      structure.forEach(page => {
        fse.mkdir(`./pages/${page.name}`, () => {
          fse.mkdir(`./pages/${page.name}/page`, () => {
            fse.writeFile(`./pages/${page.name}/page/index.tsx`, `template`);
          });
          fse.writeFile(`./pages/${page.name}/index.tsx`, `api`);
        });
      });
    });
    fse.writeFile(`./pages/index.tsx`, `index`);
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

This will work but I don't like the callback chain, haven't tried fs.extra yet but looks like it would solve that callback pyramid perhaps

Comment: try [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/ensureDir.md)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far :)

Comment: here you go @eol :) but to be honest I don't like my solution, wondering if doing it with python would be cleaner